# Dropping an unindexed table with over 1.7 Billion rows on live database (SQL Admin Nightmare)

Tags: sql-server, database, bigdata

A recent employee of our company had a stored procedure that has gone haywire, and caused mass inserts into a debug table of his. The table is unindexed, is now at close to 1.7 billion rows, and is taking up so much space that the backup no longer fits on the backup drive (Backups now reach close to 250GB).

I haven't really seen anything like this, so I'm seeking advice from the MSSQL Gurus out here.

I know I could nibble away at the table, but being unindexed, the `DELETE FROM [TABLE] WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP 10000 [ID] FROM [TABLE])` nearly locks up the server searching for them.

I also don't want my log file to get massive, it's currently sitting at 480GB on a 1TB drive. If I delete this table, will I be able to shrink it back down? (My recovery mode is simple)

We could index the id field on the table, though we only have around 9 hours downtime a day, and during business hours we can't be locking up the database.

Just looking for advice here, and a point in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll get an answer to this problem here, but consider improving your monitoring system in addition. When the disk runs out of space during production hours it's not a fun time.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to consider `TRUNCATE`

MSDN reference: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621(v=sql.80).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> Removes all rows from a table without logging the individual row deletes.

Syntax:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [YOUR_TABLE]
```

As @Rahul suggests in the comments, you could also use `DROP TABLE [YOUR_TABLE]` if you no longer plan to use the table in question. The `TRUNCATE` option would simply empty the table but leave it in place if you wanted to continue to use it.

With regards to the space issue, both of these operations will be comparatively quick and the space will be reclaimed, but it won't happen instantly. When using `TRUNCATE`, the data still has to be deleted, but SQL Server will simply deallocate the data pages used by the table and use a background process to actually perform the clean up afterwards.

[This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30325/delete-vs-truncate) should provide some useful information.

Comment: You don't say if you need to keep any of the records in the table, but if you do, then copy those first to a new table and then truncate this one as suggested here. Then you can drop this table and rename the new one to the old table name.

Comment: @HLGEM he talks about dropping and deleting the table so I didn't consider that he wanted to keep any of the data

Comment: @HLGEM just re-reading your comment and I wasn't sure if it was directed at OP rather than my answer? Either way, that's the way to go if some records need to be kept

Comment: Why would it be so different than `drop table`?

Comment: `drop` would be fine if the table was no longer required

Comment: I was directing it to the OP.  Also to future readers who might need to save some data.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be ... take the back up of only that `1.7 billion rows table` (probably in a tape drive/somewhere with good enough space) and then drop the table saying `drop table table_name`.

That way, if at all that debug table data is needed in future; you have a copy and can restore from backup.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the logging for this table and launch a delete stored procedure that would commit every 1000 rows.